Add vertical spcae before abstract chapter
I want to have extra vertical space before the headers "Abstract" and "Zusammenfassung" only - the "normal chapter" spacing is good as it is.
Without using the titlesec package! This destroys my whole document..
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
parskip=half,
toc=bibliography,
numbers=noendperiod,
cleardoublepage=plain
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
left=3cm,
right=2.5cm,
top=2.5cm,
bottom=2.0cm,
includehead,
includefoot
]{geometry}

\newenvironment{abstract}{}{}
\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand\chapterheadstartvskip{\addvspace{-4ex}}

\begin{document}
    \newpage

    \addchap{Abstract}
    Abstract in English
    
    \addchap{Zusammenfassung}
    Abstract in German
    
    \newpage
    
    \chapter{some chapter with normal spacing}
\end{document}


Localize the effect of \chapterheadstartvskip. For the example, I use 24ex, choose what you prefer.
I also use oneside for the example, in order to see two pages side-by-side.
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  parskip=half,
  toc=bibliography,
  numbers=noendperiod,
  cleardoublepage=plain,
oneside,% just for the example
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage[
  left=3cm,
  right=2.5cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.0cm,
  includehead,
  includefoot
]{geometry}

\newenvironment{abstracts}{%
  \renewcommand\chapterheadstartvskip{\addvspace{24ex}}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstracts}

\addchap{\abstractname}

Abstract in English
    
\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
\addchap{\abstractname}

Abstract in German
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{abstracts}

\chapter{some chapter with normal spacing}

\end{document}


